# Blink image with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to blink a image with JQuery?

I need to blink certain image with specific class. It should work in both IE and firefox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392930/is-there-a-blink-plugin-in-jquery-to-implement-the-following

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function blink(time, interval){
    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        $("img").css("opacity", "0.1");
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("img").css("opacity", "1");
        }, 100);
    }, interval);
    window.setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(timer);}, time);
}
```

And start function with `blink(900000, 1000);`

Comment: i wanted to blink my image for 15 min

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function() {window.setInterval("$('.myImage').toggle();",2000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

15 minutes? You could give jQuery Timers a try (http://jquery.offput.ca/every/)