# How to have images fade in and out at same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using the following bit of js to cycle through a series of images. As it works now, one animation does not start until the last one has completed - so image fades out, and then new image fades in.

```
var j = 0;
var delay = 2000; //millisecond delay between cycles
function cycleThru(){
    var jmax = $("#hero-slides li").length -1;
    $("#hero-slides li:eq(" + j + ")")
        .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,1000)
        .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
        .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 1000, function(){
            (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
            cycleThru();
        });
    };
    cycleThru();
```

I would really like to have the fade in and out happen at the same time, is that possible with this code?

Thanks, as always.

Comment: It's similar to this question: 
Blink image with JQuery
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139477/blink-image-with-jquery>?

Answer (score 0):

set the delay of the last animation to 1000 instead of 2000 that way you'll have overlapping animations, the problem is that you'll probably need to set one of them to take position absolute, probably the one fading out so it don't overflow the container.

sorry i didin't read your code well try this

```
function cycleThru(){
    var jmax = $("#hero-slides li").length -1;
    $("#hero-slides li:eq(" + j + ")")
     .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,1000,function(){
        (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
        setTimeout(cycleThru,delay);
     })
     .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,delay
     .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 1000);
 };
cycleThru();
```

moving the invoking function to after the first animation is done and scheduling the next image to appear right at the same time that the current image should fade away, that should work

Comment: Oh sorry, it is set to 1000, that was just a typo. Edited my question above. All images are already set to an absolute position.